# Is there a way to open all the youtube videos with VLC?

Tags: video, vlc-media-player, youtube

I am trying to restrict the YouTube videos as much as possible, including the search bar of the YouTube. However, there are many important videos for me on the Youtube. Therefore, I want to be able to access the individual YouTube videos from the VLC, which will give me the individual video only. Do you know if it is possible to access the YouTube videos with VLC without copy pasting the URL but rather having it opened as soon as I click on a YouTube video link?

Comment: The YouTube website entirely is blocked on my machine.

Comment: Just a comment, but I would be skeptical a solution to this problems already exists. It seems more probable that you would need to create your own third-party solution(s) (e.g. browser extension, browser script, etc.) to "get"/"process"/"alter" YouTube links and somehow open them with VLC.